# How to add variable from one dataframe to another dataframe (several conditions)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I had a read through the existing topics, but nothing I've read matched the thing I want to do.

dataframe 1: newdata (excerpt)

```
country year      sector    emissions
Austria 1990       Total    6.229223e+04
Austria 1990   Regulated    3.826440e+04
Austria 1990 Unregulated    2.402783e+04
Austria 1991       Total    6.589968e+04
Austria 1991   Regulated    3.931820e+04
Austria 1991 Unregulated    2.658148e+04
```

dataframe 2: EUETS (excerpt)

```
country         year  emissions
Austria         2005  164925659
Belgium         2005  282762153
Croatia         2005          0
Cyprus          2005   16021583
Czech Republic  2005  288986144
Denmark         2005  171815416
Estonia         2005   71336242
```

What I want to do:

- Add information from `EUETS$emissions` to a new column `newdata$EUETS`
- this insertation should be based on country and year and be inserted in the row for this country and year where `newdata$sector = "regulated"`
- `newdata$sector = "unregulated"` and `newdata$sector = "Total"` need to receive `NA` and under no circumstances `0`
- if there is no corresponding information in `EUETS$country` and/or `EUETS$year`, `NA` should be inserted into `newdata$EUETS`
- if there is information in `EUETS$emissions`, but no matching year and/or country for this in `newdata`, a new row shall be created for this information filling in the values from `EUETS` as above, but inserting `NA` in the new cells for `newdata$emissions = Total` and `newdata$unregulated`.

This should look like this:

```
country         year      sector    emissions     EUETS
Austria         1990       Total    6.229223e+04  NA
Austria         1990   Regulated    3.826440e+04  2516843
Austria         1990 Unregulated    2.402783e+04  NA
Austria         1991       Total    6.589968e+04  NA
Austria         1991   Regulated    3.931820e+04  446656
Austria         1991 Unregulated    2.658148e+04  NA
Liechtenstein   2005 Total          NA            NA
Liechtenstein   2005 Regulated      NA            654612641
Liechtenstein   2005 Unregulated    NA            NA
```

Liechtenstein was only in `EUETS$country` and didn't exist in `newdata$country` and was consequently added to the latter dataframe.

This may be several questions/post in one, but I hope this is appropriate to ask here. I tried myself a few things, but didn't manage especially when it comes to filling in the values into the existing columns in newdata (country and year).

I appreciate help with any part of this task.

Thanks so much in advance!

Nordsee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change the EUETS column names and sector as you want the to show up in the end:

```
names(EUETS)[3] = "EUETS"
EUETS$sector = "Regulated"
```

Make sure your original sector column is a character, not a factor:

```
newdata$sector = as.character(newdata$sector)
```

Merge the data

```
result = merge(newdata, EUETS, all = TRUE)
```

For adding unrepresented countries back into `EUETS`, I'm not sure what `year` and `emissions` values you want to add in, so I'll ignore that for now. But basically you want to use `merge` again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far. Concerning the last bit, I want to add the countries and years which are in `EUETS`, but not represented in `newdata` to be added to `newdata`. as `newdata` won't have values for `newdata$emissions` or `results$emissions`, I want to fill in `NA`. Basically, both dataframes should be merged when it comes to `results$emissions`. The code is only doing this (adding a year which is only in `EUETS`), if the country also exists in `newdata`.

Comment: A concrete example would make it clear what you want. Here's what I don't understand: (1) Is "adding these rows to `newdata`" different from creating the result we've already done? If not, then I think the above solution already does that, take a look a `result` and see if you agree. All countries from either data frame are in `result`...

Comment: (2) If instead you want to keep `result` separate but still go back and add these countries to `newdata`, then please give a concrete example. Here's a good start:  Let's say that `EUETS` has two rows like this: `data.frame(country = c("Elbonia", "Elbonia"), year = c(2005, 2010), emissions = c(0, 12345))`, and that `Elbonia` doesn't appear in `newdata`. I understand that we want to and `country = "Elbonia"` to `newdata`, but I don't know...

Comment: (a) do we want to add one or two rows? Do we take the years from `EUTS` as well? (b) What should  the `sector` be for these new rows? `"regulated"`, like the other data we pulled from `EUETS`, or something else? (c) Do you still want to to the same renaming of the `EUETS` emissions column, or something else?

Comment: thanks again for your answer. I must have had senior moment yesterday. Everything works as it should. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer might have been misleading, contributing to the misunderstanding. Glad we got to a working solution!